# Efficient way to Convert UTC time to Epoch in millisecond in Python in a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

How to Convert UTC time to epoch in a python DataFrame in an efficient manner ?

**Here is what I have:**

```
df = pd.DataFrame(['2017-12-12T00:59:54', '2017-12-12T01:09:52', '2017-12-12T01:19:51'], columns = ['time'])
```

**Here is what I did:**

```
import datetime as dt

epoch = []
for x in df['time']:
    dt = datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
    epoch.append(dt.replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc).timestamp())

df['epoch'] = epoch
```

**Here is my Issue:**

This `for` loop seems to be very slow in a large pandas data frame, is there a more efficient way to do it?

Thank you! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me working:

```
df['epoch'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time']).astype(np.int64) // 10**9
print (df)

                  time       epoch
0  2017-12-12T00:59:54  1513040394
1  2017-12-12T01:09:52  1513040992
2  2017-12-12T01:19:51  1513041591
```

Comment: What is the 10**9 part @jezrael ? :)

Comment: @Matthew - data are in nanoseconds, for remove last `0` need divide by `10**9` - epoch in seconds

Comment: so in milliseconds will be 10 ** 3 ?

Comment: @Matthew - I think `10**6`